# Grand Central Dispatch. When using GCD [spinner startAnimating] similar to [myView setNeedsDisplay]?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

In Grand Central Dispatch I want to start a spinner - `UIActivityIndicatorView` - spinning prior to beginning long running task:

```
dispatch_async(cloudQueue, ^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                [self spinnerSpin:YES];
            });

    [self performLongRunningTask];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                [self spinnerSpin:NO];
             });


});
```

Here is the `spinnerSpin` method:

```
- (void)spinnerSpin:(BOOL)spin {

    ALog(@"spinner %@", (YES == spin) ? @"spin" : @"stop");

    if (spin == [self.spinner isAnimating]) return;

    if (YES == spin) {

        self.hidden = NO;
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
    } else {

        [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        self.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

One thing I have never seen discussed is the difference - if any - between `[myView setNeedsDisplay]` and `[myActivityIndicatorView startAnimating]`. Do they behave the same?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: I would suggest removing the `grand-central-dispatch` tag from this question, as it has nothing to do with GCD. Also, the more generic `ios` tag could be more appropriate than `ios5`, as the `UIActivityIndicatorView` class has been there since the beginning.

Comment: Not sure I follow. GCD is the acronymn for Grand Central Dispatch. No?

Comment: Also, if memory serves, GCD was not available prior to iOS4 so using an iOS tag is not correct.

Comment: Well, even though your specific scenario involves Grand Central Dispatch (aka GCD), your question is about the difference between [UIView setNeedsDisplay] and [UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating], which has nothing to do with GCD. The question could be asked without mentioning GCD at all and the answer would still be the same.

Comment: On the contrary. My question is fundamentally about the behavior of UI updating in the context of GCD. Further the spinner behavior at a fundamental level is a UI updating behavior and is thus relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]` method has nothing to do with a `UIActivityIndicatorView`'s animation state.

`setNeedsDisplay` simply informs the system that this view's state has changed in a way that invalidates its currently drawn representation. In other words, it asks the system to invoke that view's `drawRect` method on the next drawing cycle.

You very rarely need to invoke `setNeedsDisplay` from outside of a view, from code that is consuming the view. This method is meant to be invoked by the view's internal logic code, whenever something changes in its internal state that requires a redraw of the view.

The `[UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating]` method is specific to the `UIActivityIndicatorView` class and simply asks the indicator to start animating (e.g. spinning). This method is instant, without requiring you to call any other method.

On a side note, you could simplify your code by simply calling `startAnimating` or `stopAnimating` without manually showing/hiding it. The `UIActivityIndicatorView` class has a `hidesWhenStopped` boolean property that defaults to `YES`, which means that the spinner will show itself as soon as it starts animating, and hide itself when it stops animating.

So your `spinnerSpin:` method could be refactored like this (as long as you haven't set the `hidesWhenStopped` property to `NO`):

```
- (void)spinnerSpin:(BOOL)spin {
    if (YES == spin) {
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
    } else {
        [self.spinner stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest moving the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` call to the `spinnerSpin:` method, so it could be called from any place in your code without having to explicitly dispatching it to the main queue.